# Bind DataGridColumnHeader with selected row's property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

Consider the following ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel 
{
    public ObservableCollection<Foo> foos { get; set; }
}

[PropertyChanged.ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string NameHeader { get; set; }
}
```

Note that I am using [Fody's PropertyChanged](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) to make my ViewModel properties implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

And I have the following `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="FooTable"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=foos}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          CanUserAddRows="True"
          AutomationProperties.IsColumnHeader="True"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          SelectionUnit="FullRow">

          <DataGrid.Columns>
              <DataGridTextColumn 
                  Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                  Header="{Binding NameHeader, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                  Width="Auto" />
          </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The Binding of `Header` with `NameHeader` won't work! Ofcourse then I realized that different Rows will have different values of `NameHeader`.

So what I really want is to **bind column's `Header` with selected row's `NameHeader`**. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `HeaderTemplate` with a `TextBlock` that binds to the `SelectedItem` property of the `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="Auto">
    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.NameHeader, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```